# light slider refresh not working

Tags: jquery, slider

"slider.refresh()" not working on click event in light slider. Document have this refresh function but i get this error

Uncaught TypeError: slider.refresh is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var slider = $(".content-slider").lightSlider({
    loop:false,
    keyPress:true,
    verticalHeight:500,
    item:1,
    auto:false,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    enableTouch: true,
    enableDrag: false,
    freeMove:true,
});

   // Save note show div
    $('.save-note').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.col-sm-12').
        find('.note-section').removeClass('hide').fadeIn('slow');
        slider.refresh();
   });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Declaring the slider again will cause a new instance of the slider inside the container.

1. You need to save your instance of the slider in a global variable in the window scope:

   ```
   window.globals = {
       gallery: ""
   };
   ```
2. After you have initialized your slider, save it to the globals object created:

   ```
   var slider = $("#lightSlider").lightSlider();

   window.globals = {
       gallery: slider
   };
   ```
3. Then when you need to refresh the slider you call it this way:

   ```
   globals.gallery.refresh();
   ```

Same with the rest of available methods, for instance:

```
    globals.gallery.goToSlide(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the slider var again:

```
// Save note show div
    $('.save-note').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.col-sm-12').
        find('.note-section').removeClass('hide').fadeIn('slow');
        var slider = $(".content-slider").lightSlider(); // declare var again
        slider.refresh();
   });
```